# Fatal error when I am using toArray() in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, toarray

I need help to remove fatal error of `toArray()` in zend framework.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object

I am using following code in my controller

```
$obj     = new Admin_Model_UserMapper();
$where   = array('id = ?'=>$decryptId);
$data    = $obj->fetchAll($where);
//  $currentData = $data->current();
$dataArr = $data->toArray();


$form = new Admin_Form_UserForm();
$form->setAction('edit-user');
$form->populate($dataArr);
```

I am getting fatal error in both condition when I use `toArray()` or `current()`.

I have already used following code, but not getting any solution and it produces the same error:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$select = $db->select()->from('user')->where('id= ?',$decryptId);
$stmt = $select->query();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
if(count($result) > 0){
    $dataArr = $result->toArray();
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Try `var_dump($result);exit;` right after the fetchAll to see what `$result` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `fetchAll` returns no data. Wrap it in a condition...

```
$where = array('id = ?'=>$decryptId);
$data  = $obj->fetchAll($where);
if ($data->count()){
    //  $currentData = $data->current();
    $dataArr = $data->toArray();
}else{
    // no records found!
}
```

The problem is with your `$where`, you cannot use it like key/value array. Use code below:

```
$where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $decriptId);
```

Comment: Perhaps it is better to use is_object($data) in if().. and ZF TDG have method to find record by id(primary key): $obj->find($id); 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.find